# Is it possible to iterate over a multi-dimensional array in smarty?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, smarty

Can someone provide a simple demo?  I can't seem to get my head around the [smarty syntax](http://www.smarty.net/) for iterating over an array that looks like the one below.  I want to get at values at all levels.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0
            [name] => 12312
            [sub24] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [classid] => 157
                            [classname] => 24011010
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [classid] => 170
                            [classname] => 24011020
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [classid] => 183
                            [classname] => 24011030
                        )

                )

            [sub23] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [classid] => 60
                            [classname] => 23011010
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [classid] => 73
                            [classname] => 23011030
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [classid] => 85
                            [classname] => 23012030
                        )


                )

            [sub22] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [classid] => 1
                            [classname] => 22011010
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [classid] => 13
                            [classname] => 22012010
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [classid] => 24
                            [classname] => 22012020
                        )

                )

        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not tested, but from the top of my head, something like this.

Note: I'm doing it like this because you said you wanted Smarty Syntax. Normally I'd stuff this into a helper function, create the list/table/whatever there, and just call the helper function from within Smarty.

```
<html>
<head><title>Smarty Foreach Demo</title></head>
<body>
<p>This code assumes you have $smarty->assign()'ed $var to be your multi-dimensional array</p>

<ul>
{foreach from=$var key=key1 item=lvl1}
    <li>Current key: $key1,
    Current value:
    {if !is_array($lvl1)}
       {$lvl1}
    {else}
       Array:<ul>
       {foreach from=$lvl1 key=key2 item=lvl2}
           <li>Current key: $key1,
           Current value:
           {if !is_array($lvl1)}
               {$lvl1}
           {else}
               Even deeper array.. keep doing same stuff!
           {/if}
           </li>
       {/foreach}
       </ul>
   {/if}
 {/foreach}
</ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like how you iterate over a PHP array:

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) for example.

```
foreach ($array as $i => $value) {
    PrintValue($i, $value);
}

function PrintValue($key, $val)
{
    echo $key;
   if(is_array($val))
   {
      foreach($val as $i=>$value)
      {
          PrintValue($i, $value);
      }
   }
   else
   {
      echo $val;
   }
}
```

Or, you can use `$print_r($arr)`, this would print everything inside an array, including the array inside array element.

Comment: It's similar but not exactly the same.Can you give a working demo?

Answer (score 1):

see [smarty doc](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.function.section.php) here (example 7.33)

Answer (score 0):

```
{foreach from=$multi_array item=i}

    {if is_array($i) && count($i) > 0}

        {foreach from=$i item=j} <!-- if it is an array, lets create a loop from item=i, note the "$" in from=$i -->

            Class id: {$j.classid}<br />
            Class name: {$j.classname}<br />

        {/foreach}

    {else}

        {$i} <!-- will print id/name of your array -->

    {/if}

{/foreach}
```